# Why does awk '{print "Hi, Judy"}' print "Hi, Judy" repeatedly when pressing Return?

Tags: awk

For my understanding, usually `awk` follows a file or an output.

Then it will exec its code on everyline of that file or output.

In my case, my command `awk '{print "Hi, Judy"}'` didn't follow by any file or output.

To my understanding, it should print out nothing or raise up an error.

But why in reality, it pomps out an interactive command line in which if I keep on pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd>, it will show me something infinitely like:

```
Hi, Judy

Hi, Judy

Hi, Judy
```

Why this command works like that?

# *content below this dividing line should be ignored*

---

#### Addtional Question:

I tried another command:

```
awk ' BEGIN { print "Hi." }  { print "Buddy." } { print "Bye." } '
```

I'm expecting it will print `Hi. Buddy. Bye.` Infinitely.

But I got:

```
Hi.

Buddy
Bye.

Buddy
Bye.

Buddy
Bye.
```

Which confusing me again. Why the `END clause` works infinitely, meanwhile `BEGIN clause` only works once here?

Comment: It has to work that way, how else would you use `awk` in a pipeline, which is the most common usage? Such as `sort myfile | awk '{ print $2 }'` or something similar?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's reading from stdin, i.e. your keyboard.

Try this to see what I mean

```
awk '{ print "Here is your line:", $0 }'
```

Comment: So if awk follows by nothing, it will reads standard-input, is it right?

Comment: Exactly - it's perfect for using in a pipeline, most core utilities read from stdin if no file is given for input.

Comment: @roaima, I've updated my question, do you know the reason for the extra question?

Comment: @Zen Your code is incorrect: there is no `END` clause in it, otherwise it would be printed once, like the `BEGIN` block, but at the end of your data stream. [Here is a little bit more information about `awk`](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/awk.html). (by the way, please avoid asking several questions in one ; this doesn't really fit in this community's format ;))

Comment: @JohnWHSmith, yes, I made a terrible mistake here.

Comment: Well the additional question is sort of related to the first, so not a capitol (capital?) offense I think.

Comment: @Zen normally it would be best to ask this as a new question because you've already got an answer to the question you asked. However... the reason is given in the "Here is a little bit more information about awk" reference that John WH Smith has mentioned. Each `awk` line comprises an expression and an action. If the expression is empty it defaults to _true_. If the action is empty is defaults to `print $0`. Your first action is tagged with `BEGIN`. The remaining two actions apply to every line of input.